Playwright onEnd() results does not include duration like documentation specifies. What am I missing?
The build in method onEnd can has a results object that can be accessed within the onEnd function. Per the documentation here, it will include the property duration which is number in milliseconds. When I try and access results.duration the value is undefined.
The following code block should include the start time, duration and result of the entire run of tests. It does not. The only property that is defined is result.status.
async onEnd(result): Promise<void> {
    const suiteData: LogSuiteData = {
        "@timeStamp": result.startTime,
        suiteDuration: result.duration,
        suiteResult: result.status,
    };

    logArray.push(suiteData);

    await logCallHandler.postReportDataBatch(logArray);
}

Further digging lead me to the Playwright type FullResult which has no mentions in the documentation but the defined type within the Playwright types only has the status property, as seen in this screenshot.
Are the official Playwright docs incorrect? Am I doing something wrong? Any help is appreciated.
Additional info, I'm currently using version 1.34.1.

Please share your package.json and a runnable, complete [mcve]. Thanks. You're using durationMinutes not duration.

You're using result.durationMinutes rather than result.duration. The following complete example works for me with @playwright/test ^1.42.1:
pw-reporter.js:
class MyReporter {
  onEnd(result) {
    console.log(result.duration);
  }
}

module.exports = MyReporter;

playwright.config.js:
import {defineConfig} from "@playwright/test";

export default defineConfig({
  reporter: [["./pw-reporter.js"]]
};

pw.test.js:
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test";

test("1 is 1", async ({page}) => {
  await expect(1).toBe(1);
});

Run npx playwright test and see the duration, 414.995 or similar.

As a side note, the docs appear to have a typo:
export default defineConfig({
  reporter: ['./my-awesome-reporter.ts', { customOption: 'some value' }],
});

should be:
export default defineConfig({
  reporter: [['./my-awesome-reporter.ts', { customOption: 'some value' }]],
});

I've PRed a fix.
